# ¿Cómo agregar QLabel dinámicamente?

Tags: c++, qt, clase

El contexto es que tengo un *QList* y debo crear un QLabel por cada elemento que haya en ese QList y claramente los QLabel se deben ir viendo en la ventana hacia abajo. Esto debe hacerse inmediatamente al abrir la ventana, por lo que no dispongo de ningún *QPushButton* ni nada parecido.
Adjunto el código de la ventana:

```
#include "produccion.h"
#include "ui_produccion.h"
#include "structs.h"

Produccion::Produccion(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Produccion)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Desde aquí creo una lista con los nombres que deseo en los 
    //labels, es solo una prueba. ListaPaquetes es una struct
    ListaPaquetes *nuevoPaquete = new ListaPaquetes();
    nuevoPaquete->crearPaquete(4,"paquetito");
    nuevoPaquete->crearPaquete(10,"paquete");
    nuevoPaquete->crearPaquete(16,"tubo");
    QList<QString> tiposPaquetes = nuevoPaquete->paquetesAgregados();

    //Aquí uso el for para recorrer el array e ir tomando el texto que 
    //quiero en los label
    for (int i=0; i<tiposPaquetes.length();i++)
    {
        int contador = 0;
        int ejex = 60;
        int ejey = 60;
        QString nombreBoton = "label" + QString::number(contador);
        QLabel *nombreBoton;
        nombreBoton = new QLabel(this,"Hola",nombreBoton);
        nombreBoton->setGeometry(ejex,ejey,121,121);
        contador++;
        ejey += 50;
    }
}

Produccion::~Produccion()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Produccion::on_Produccion_accepted()
{

}
```

Los errores que muestra son:

```
conflicting declaration 'QLabel* nombreBoton'
         QLabel *nombreBoton;

no matching function for call to 'QLabel::QLabel(Produccion*, const char [5], QString&)'
         nombreBoton = new QLabel(this,"Hola",nombreBoton);

no matching function for call to 'QLabel::QLabel(Produccion*, const char [5], QString&)'
         nombreBoton = new QLabel(this,"Hola",nombreBoton);*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error 1**

```
conflicting declaration 'QLabel* nombreBoton'
         QLabel *nombreBoton;
```

¿Donde se produce?

```
QString nombreBoton = "label" + QString::number(contador);
QLabel *nombreBoton; // <--- AQUI
```

¿Por qué?

Porque no puedes tener dos variables compartiendo nombre y ámbito. Fíjate que  el `QString` que declaras en la línea anterior tiene el mismo nombre.

¿Solución?

Dale un nombre diferente al objeto:

```
QString nombreBoton = "label" + QString::number(contador);
QLabel *label; // por ejemplo
```

**Error 2**

```
no matching function for call to 'QLabel::QLabel(Produccion*, const char [5], QString&)'
         nombreBoton = new QLabel(this,"Hola",nombreBoton);
```

¿Dónde se produce?

```
nombreBoton = new QLabel(this,"Hola",nombreBoton);
```

¿Por qué?

No existe ningún constructor que acepte una cadena como tercer parámetro:

```
QLabel(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
QLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
```

¿Solución?

Llama a las funciones propias de cada clase y ajústate a su interfaz.

Asumiendo, por la pinta del código, que `Produccion` hereda de `QWidget`, el código podría quedar así:

```
label = new QLabel("Hola",this);
label->setObjectName(nombreboton);
```

Comment: Se me quitaron varios errores pero ahora me dice que setName no existe, y de hecho cuando intenté poner la _->_ no me dio esa opción, ¿Cuál es el que habría que usar?

Comment: @FabricioCeciliano lo siento, es `setObjectName` fallo mío

Comment: Listo, problema resuelto. ¿Para crear spinbox es de la misma forma?

Comment: @FabricioCeciliano si, pero acostumbrate a consultar la documentación al respecto ya que ahí suele venir todo lo que necesitas